# Installing windows 7 next to linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, grub

I installed backtrack to a netbook drive but how do you install windows 7 and get dualboot? It has the grub bootloader installed. Does Windows have a dualboot option for install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 does not have the ability to configure "dual boot" or any sort of configuration for the boot system during installation. You will have to do such configuration after installation is done (either re-install grub to the MBR or configure the windows boot "BCD" menu to work with grub). However Windows does automatically setup multi-booting for Microsoft products.

Comment: This is the preferred option. Windows first, then Linux, or at the very least, reconfigure grub last. I don't know what the impact of Windows 8 is going to be, though.

Comment: @RandolphWest I haven't heard good things about W8's boot loader D:

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have Windows and BackTrack Linux using Dual Boot, check this out:

[Dual Boot BackTrack And Windows7 - BackTrack Linux](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/Dual_Boot_BackTrack_And_Windows7)